# Enlarge emgucv object mcvbox2d to a rectangle object

Tags: c#, emgucv

I want to enlarge a mcvbox2d object to a rectangle object

First what I did was getting a box-shaped contour from a contour object. Then, I extracted all corners of the box. Did sorting of all of the corners. After that, offset 5 pixel from the corners and enlarged width and height to 10 pixel bigger

```
MCvBox2D box = approxContour.GetMinAreaRect();

PointF[] corners = box.GetVertices();

corners = corners.OrderBy(s => s.X).ThenBy(s => s.Y).ToArray();

Rectangle enlargedROI = new Rectangle((int)Math.Round(corners[0].X), (int)Math.Round(corners[0].Y), (int) Math.Round(box.size.Width), (int)Math.Round(box.size.Height));

enlargedROI.X -= 5; 
enlargedROI.Y -= 5;
enlargedROI.Width += 10;    
enlargedROI.Height += 10;
```

moreover I need to also check, whether the enlarged box must be within the image size. Not fulfilling this condition the box will be removed from this checking.

However, the thing which bothered me was getting negative values of the corners. This made me wondering whether Mcvbox2d (0,0) point starts from the center of the box.

Have anyone got any clue about this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I finally got my own solution for this. Indeed, McVBox2 has center value, which means I have to do my own calculation to get left-top corner coordinate for the box. I also did the off-boundary checking. below is the code.

```
enlargedROI.X -= 3; //offset by 3 pixel
enlargedROI.Y -= 3;
enlargedROI.Width += 60;    //enlarge to 60px
enlargedROI.Height += 30;

if (!(enlargedROI.X < 0) && !(enlargedROI.Y < 0))
{
    if (!(enlargedROI.Width + enlargedROI.X > gray.Width) && !(enlargedROI.Height + enlargedROI.Y > gray.Height))
    {

        box.Offset(-3, -3);
        box.size = new SizeF(box.size.Width + 60, box.size.Height + 30);

        Image<Gray, Byte> plate = imageToOCR.Copy(box);
        //further implementation

     }
```